# How do I add a tab on a viewcontroller that doesnt have an icon on its own in xcode?

Tags: xcode, uitabcontroller

How do I add a tab on a viewcontroller that doesnt have a tab icon on its own ?

I created a tab controller which is linked to major view controllers that has their own icon. but what about minor controllers? i want minor controllers to have a tab controller on their lower screen, which has icons linked on the major view controllers.